# Bound to WrapPanel but not updatind in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to build a dynanmic list of buttons (or whatever element is in the template, doesn't really matter.., my XAML is:

```
    <Button Content="Add New Button" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="AddNewButton" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ButtonsList}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Height="40" MinWidth="40" Content="{Binding Name}" Margin="2"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

My code behind looks like this:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ButtonsList = new ObservableCollection<ShortcutButton>();

    }

    public class ShortcutButton
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ShortcutButton> ButtonsList { get; set; }

    private void AddNewButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tblock.Text += "Button Clicked" + Environment.NewLine;
        ButtonsList.Add(new ShortcutButton() { Name = "New button title" });
    }
```

When I debug, I can see that objects are being added to the ButtonsList Observable Collection, but it does not update in the bound WrapPanel in ItemsControl.. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Based on the code you've shown, I'd say all you really need to do is move the `ButtonsList = ...` assignment that's in the constructor, to _before_ the call to `InitializeComponent()`. Impossible to say for sure without a good [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Binding is incorrect, by default it will try to search for a property named ButtonList in the DataContext. To bind your ItemsSource to your ButtonList defined in the MainWindow you should change the RelativeSource like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ButtonsList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}">
```

Comment: It tells me MainWindow is not supported in WPF application

Comment: Try to build the project and see if it detects it.

Comment: Set this on top of the XAML inside the <Window> node: xmlns:local="clr-namespace:<Namespace of your MainWindow". Or else try to replace "local:MainWindow" by just "MainWindow". This works with me so there should be a way to allow it.